# Is there a way to change a nextcord button color's when it is clicked?

Tags: python, nextcord

I am making a discord bot using nextcord. My goal is to make a nextcord button change color when it is clicked.

Here is my button:

```
class button(nextcord.ui.View):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
  @nextcord.ui.button(label=" ", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.gray, row=0)
  async def test(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
    #color change here
```

*the following codes go where `#color change here` is

I have tried:

- `button.style(nextcord.ButtonStyle.green)`
- `button.style = nextcord.ButtonStyle.green`

Just making another button class and replacing it is not an option, as this is for a bigger project, and there would be too many classes.

Does anyone know a way to change the button's color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
class button(nextcord.ui.View):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
  class button_innerclass(nextcord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super.__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    
    async def callback(self,interactions):
        self.Buttonstyle="somme Buttonstyle"
        "Place callback code here"

  self.add_item(button_innertclass(label="style changing button"))
```

Advantages:
You can change the attributes from the button on runtime.
You don't have to create another external class.

And even if it is a bigger project, you should have the structure to create separate classes.